# Any mathematical term for a function with all its characteristic parameters assigned to numbers?

Tags: functions

If I have a simple function such as y = a.x + b, then this is a parameterised function obviously.

Now, after we assign actual values for 'a' and 'b', such as a = 1 and b = 2, then we would get y = x + 2.

Is there a term for the function for the case where the characteristic parameters have numbers assigned to them? Eg. a 'numerised function'?

I don't think I can call it an 'evaluated function' because an evaluated function would be going a step further and getting an actual number (result) for 'y'.

I just wanted to ask if there is a term for a function that has its characteristic parameters (quantities) assigned to an actual value.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not describe $y=mx+a$ as parametrised as there is no parameter involved.  The parametrised form of that equation would be:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
x & = & t \\
y & = & mt +a 
\end{eqnarray}$$
where $t$ is the parameter.  There's not a lot of difference in this simple case between this and what you wrote, obviously.

The equation with $a,b$ unknown is the *general* equation, and when values are given is a *specific* or *particular* equation.  If you have touched on ODEs before then you'll recognise this terminology from there as well, as *general solution* and *particular solution*.

Comment: Thanks very much postmortes for teaching me that terminology. I'll remember that forever, and it's going to help me a lot. Thanks also for going out of your way with the definition of parameter. That makes a big difference. I was thinking along the wrong lines of characteristic parameters --- eg. 'm' being slope or gradient, and 'a' being y-intercept. Thanks again postmortes! Really appreciated.

Comment: @Kenny my pleasure, I'm glad it helped :)  In the interests of keeping the site tidy, if you're happy with the answer you can click the tick icon by it to accept it -- that marks it as answered and should get you a little reputation as well.